# YelpSharp : Get all search Result

Tags: c#, windows, yelp

i want to use yelp search engine in my desktop application to get all location  but i have a big problem.in fact, i can get only 20 business searched in my request.i think that maybe exist a limit parameter in SearchOption used in YelpSharp but i can just get 20 result in max.

```
Yelp y = new Yelp(options);
List<Business> SearchList = new List<Business>();
List<YelpSharp.Data.Business> l = new List<YelpSharp.Data.Business>();
SearchOptions searchOptions = new SearchOptions();
searchOptions.GeneralOptions = new GeneralOptions()
{
    term = "Dentist"             
};

searchOptions.LocationOptions = new LocationOptions()
{
    location = "New york"
};


 var task = y.Search(searchOptions).Result.businesses;
```

[this is the Yelp REST API used in my application](https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/YelpSharp)
Please give a response as soon as possible.

Comment: Search results for REST APIs (and even general web requests) are paginated, is the a pagination parameter or possibly a search continuation URL?

Comment: we think that is pagination problem ?

Comment: the result or search using api can be paginated ?

Comment: Any search results can be paginated, SalesForce and LinkedIn paginate.

Comment: Is no the case for Yelp. Yelp only allows to have 20 results, in some cases and 40 at most in other cases. Take a look to the parameters allowed, especially the 'sort':
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer from [Yelp Developer Support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yelp-developer-support/2SZaPLPfu3M) google groups , answer is quite disappointing :( but for having more than 20 records i.e upto 40, we can use pagination through the parameters defined in documentation [General Search Parameters](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api) section and its implementation hint is given [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/yelp-developer-support/zyEJZtlyBUA)

I used it in Ruby on Rails project , To access first `20` results

```
Yelp.client.search(params[:term], { term: 'restaurants' , limit: 20 , offset: 0 , sort: 2})
```

For results `21-40` change the value of offset

```
Yelp.client.search(params[:term], { term: 'restaurants' , limit: 20 , offset: 20 , sort: 2})
```